# Issue Printing out Pixel Values after casting to int openCV

Tags: c++, opencv, pixel

I'm haiving an issue where I can't seem to print out pixel values for an image. The image displays correctly, but instead of actually giving me three 255 values, I get

```
-2147483648
-2147483648
-2147483648
```

what gives? I don't know what I'm doing wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
     Mat baselineColor(1000,900,CV_8UC3,Scalar(255,255,255));
     //cvtColor(baselineColor,baselineColor,COLOR_BGR2HSV);
     cout << static_cast<int>(baselineColor.at<Vec3d>(10,10)[0]) << endl;
     cout << static_cast<int>(baselineColor.at<Vec3d>(10,10)[1]) << endl;
     cout << static_cast<int>(baselineColor.at<Vec3d>(10,10)[2]) << endl;
     namedWindow("Projector",WINDOW_AUTOSIZE);
     imshow("Projector",baselineColor);
     waitKey(0);
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Since you create the image with `CV_8UC3` try this: `baselineColor.at<Vec3b>(10,10)[0]`, etc. `cv::Vec3d` is for `double`

Comment: Just use `.at<Vec3b>`